# Unix shell scripting, How to add the values of a external text file lines to sed command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

i was trying to remove the lines from the log file which getting input from the txt file.
**observered_list.txt**

```
Uncaught SlingException
cannot render resource
IncludeTag Error
Recursive invocation
Reference component error
```

**Script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    EC_usr01=$(grep -c "$line" /user/admin/user01/logfile.log);
    EC_usr04=$(grep -c "$line" /user/admin/user04/logfile.log);
    EC_usr05=$(grep -c "$line" /user/admin/user05/logfile.log);
    echo "$line,$EC_usr01,$EC_usr04,$EC_usr05" >> 
done < observed_list.txt
```

with this script i was getting the output as

```
Uncaught SlingException,35,42,45
cannot render resource,25,14,28
IncludeTag Error,15,16,38
Recursive invocation,1,2,0
Reference component error,0,0,0
```

and i need to set the input values to the sed command like the following,

```
sed '/QuartzScheduler\|Uncaught SlingException\|cannot render resource\|IncludeTag Error\|Recursive invocation\|Reference component error/ d' /user/admin/user01/logfile.log > /user/admin/user01/logfile_out.txt

sed '/QuartzScheduler\|Uncaught SlingException\|cannot render resource\|IncludeTag Error\|Recursive invocation\|Reference component error/ d' /user/admin/user04/logfile.log > /user/admin/user04/logfile_out.txt

sed '/QuartzScheduler\|Uncaught SlingException\|cannot render resource\|IncludeTag Error\|Recursive invocation\|Reference component error/ d' /user/admin/user05/logfile.log > /user/admin/user05/logfile_out.txt
```

Please anyone help me to find out this and also to minimize the script.

Comment: not clear for me where is the error, You count via a grep some line and removing it after but without error.

Comment: while using 'sed /QuartzScheduler/ d' /user/admin/user05/logfile.log > /user/admin/user05/logfile_out.txt' it will remove the lines with the word  **QuartzScheduler** from logfile.log and print the remaining lines to the logfile_out.txt.

Comment: like this, i like to perform the list with the input values getting from text file and to form the following command

`sed '/QuartzScheduler\|Uncaught SlingException\|cannot render resource\|IncludeTag Error\|Recursive invocation\|Reference component error/ d' /user/admin/user05/logfile.log > /user/admin/user05/logfile_out.txt`

Comment: like, `a[0] = "QuartzScheduler", a[1]="Uncaught SlingException" a[2]="cannot render resource"` `sed '/$a[0]\|$a[1]\|$a[2]/ d' /user/admin/user05/logfile.log > /user/admin/user05/logfile_out.txt`

Comment: Please take some time to craft a proper question. Also don't post code in comments.

Comment: @thamizhinian  could you check my proposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
users="user01 user04 user05"
rx=QuartzScheduler
while read line
do
  echo -n $line
  for user in $users
  do
    echo -n ,$(grep -c "$line" /user/admin/$user/logfile.log)
  done
  echo
  rx="$rx\|$line"
done < observed_list.txt >> somelog
for user in $users
do
  sed "/$rx/ d" /user/admin/$user/logfile.log > /user/admin/$user/logfile_out.txt
done
```